# Transitive Closure vs Reachability in Graphs

Tags: graphs

I am facing the most curious situation with [my current information of] transitive closure algorithms. Specifically, is what follows not an algorithm for finding the transitive closure of a graph `G(V, E)` and is the time complexity not `O(|V|+|E|)`:

> Use Kosaraju's to compute SCCs (strongly connected components) -- O(|V| + |E|)
>
> Create a DAG from the SCCs as (super)nodes -- O(|V| + |E|)
>
> In a single supernode, reachability of all nodes is the same and equal to the union of the nodes in the containing supernode plus the reachable supernodes in the DAG -- O(|V| + |E|) to compute reachability in the DAG and O(|V| * |V|) total to compute reachability sets for all nodes

These reachability sets *do* constitute the transitive closure of the graph wholly, right?
**But there aren't any `O(|V| + |E|)` transitive closure algorithms around.**
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm is known as [Purdom's algorithm](https://algowiki-project.org/en/Purdom's_algorithm). There are two versions of transitive closure:

- Calculate the transitive closure as a relation. This cannot run in time $O(|V|+|E|)$, since the output could be bigger than that (consider a directed path, for example).
- Calculate enough information to be able to answer oracle queries to the transitive closure in $O(1)$. Even in this case, the algorithm doesn't seem to run in time $O(|V|+|E|)$. Hopefully the link would make it clear why.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This pretty much answers it. Just a couple of things: 1. What exactly is, the transitive closure as a relation? -- shortest paths between all nodes? And, are those oracle queries, limited to, _is u reachable from v_, or do they include other queries?

Comment: By “transitive closure” as a relation, I mean all pairs of points $(x,y)$ such that $y$ is reachable from $x$. Regarding oracle queries, you’re probably correct, but I suggest reading the link.

Comment: So the above algorithm runs in O(|E|+|V|^2) according to the link. And given this, the reachability set for each node can be computed in O(|V|), which would give us O(|V|^2) for computing reachability sets for all nodes, i.e the transitive closure. This gives us a O(|E|+|V|^2) transitive closure computation.